# How to distinguish between two multidimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, checkbox

I'm coding an edit form and I can't get the part where you check previously checked checkboxes to function properly.

For example I have a list of five items in a database, I previously checked two of them and saved the form. When I press edit on the form, I need to get this again:

```
[ ] Item 1
[X] Item 2
[ ] Item 3
[X] Item 4
[ ] Item 5
```

I have two arrays:

- `$amenities` All items in the database are here.
- `$related` All previously checked items are here. (in this case, two of them)

How can I walk the two arrays comparing them so if an item in `$related` is found in `$amenities`, it will print the box checked and if not, it will print it unchecked. This is my code relevant to that part.

**$amenities (print_r)**

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 3
            [itemName] => Crema Chantilly
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 4
            [itemName] => Caribe Cooler
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 5
            [itemName] => Cacahuates Japoneses
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 6
            [itemName] => Cerveza Sol (lata)
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 7
            [itemName] => Chocolate derretido
        )

)
```

**$related (print_r)**

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 3
            [itemName] => Crema Chantilly
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [itemID] => 4
            [itemName] => Caribe Cooler
        )

)
```

As you can see, there are two items in `$related` that match two items in `$amenities`.

What I'm trying here is something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($related as $single) : ?>

    <?php foreach ($amenities as $amenity) : ?>

      <?php if ( $single === $amenity) : ?>

        <input type="checkbox" class="left" checked="yes" name="amenities[]" value="<?=$amenity['itemID']?>">
        <label class="checkbox"><?=$amenity['itemName']?></label>

       <?php else : ?>

        <input type="checkbox" class="left" name="amenities[]" value="<?=$amenity['itemID']?>">
        <label class="checkbox"><?=$amenity['itemName']?></label>

      <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach;?>

<?php endforeach;?>
```

But, the results are being duplicated for the full options list. I'm getting this:

```
[X] Item 1
[ ] Item 2
[ ] Item 3
[ ] Item 4
[ ] Item 5
[ ] Item 1
[ ] Item 2
[X] Item 3
[ ] Item 4
[ ] Item 5
```

And I need to get

```
[X] Item 1
[ ] Item 2
[X] Item 3
[ ] Item 4
[ ] Item 5
```

Maybe it's something easy to do but I can't figure out how to get this done. Maybe I am taking the wrong approach with the two `foreach`?

Comment: Just so you know it is more portable to use `<?php echo` instead of `<?=`, not all systems are configured to support `<?=`. You can use `<?=` if you are sure you'll have control of every system you run the code on; but using `<?php echo` will save you some headaches if you need to move the code somewhere that doesn't support `<?=` in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I use CodeIgniter and it has the option to convert on-the-fly <?=$var=?> into <?php echo $var ?> so i think it wont be a problem as long as i keep using CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing in every loop check its existance and set its status checked

```
<?php foreach ($amenities as $single) : ?>
<?php $strChecked = '';?>
    <?php foreach ($related as $amenity) : ?>

      <?php if ( $single === $amenity) : ?>
          <?php $strChecked = ' checked="checked"';break;?>

      <?php endif ?>

    <?php endforeach;?>

        <input type="checkbox" class="left" <?php echo $strChecked;?> name="amenities[]" value="<?=$amenity['itemID']?>">
        <label class="checkbox"><?=$amenity['itemName']?></label>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but, i need to show the unchecked options too. With the code you kindly provide, i get indeed the two related options checked, but i still need to show the unchecked ones as i stated in "And i need to get" section of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with a single `foreach` loop if you use [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php
    foreach ($amenities as $amenity) {
        $id = $amenity['itemID'];
        $name = $amenity['itemName'];
        $checked = in_array($amenity, $related) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
        echo <<<HTML
        <input type="checkbox" class="left"$checked name="amenities[]" value="$id">
        <label class="checkbox">$name</label>
        <br>
HTML;
    }
?>
```

As you can see I also stored the values of `$amenity['itemID']` and `$amenity['itemName']` in variable to make the HTML code easier to read.

You could also use a slightly more complicated but more flexible approach:

';
        echo 'amenity = ' ; print_r($amenity); echo '
';
        echo 
        $name
        
    HTML;
    }

This code uses [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to create an array that contains only the `itemID`s of items in the `$related` array and then searches for the current amenity's id in that array.  This will allow you to find matching ids even if item in `$amenities` and the item in `$related` are not exactly the same (if one has extra members, etc).